# determination elasticsearch recovery failure

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering how to determine the failure of a snapshot recovery.

From the Elasticsearch documentation, cat-recovery can be used to determine if an index or indices are being recovered from some source.

Per recovering shard, the stage, one of { init, index, start, translog, finalize, done }, tells how far along in the process recovery it’s in.

In the case that for whatever reason recovery fails, would the stage come to rest at whatever stage failure occurred on? Or will stage of the failed shard transition to “done” and we can then determine failure of the recovery based on the color coded health status of said shard?

Perhaps there’s a “failure” value that I’ve missed somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

_cat/recovery is not for snapshot recovery statue. for snapshot restore failure you can get the statue as below:

```
curl XGET "127.0.0.1:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1"
```

> my_backup

is the name of repository and

> snapshot_1

is the name of snapshot you have created.

the result have these parameters:

> IN_PROGRESS

The snapshot is currently running.

> SUCCESS

The snapshot finished and all shards were stored successfully.

> FAILED

The snapshot finished with an error and failed to store any data.

> PARTIAL

The global cluster state was stored, but data of at least one shard wasn’t stored successfully. The failure section in this case should contain more detailed information about shards that were not processed correctly.

> INCOMPATIBLE

The snapshot was created with an old version of Elasticsearch and therefore is incompatible with the current version of the cluster.

Comment: the GET you posted is to see snapshot creation status, not index recovery.